# Hard drive read only on Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, read-only

Suddenly few days ago one of my hard drives on Ubuntu became read only. I can't copy any file to it or delete any file from it because it says I don't have permissions to do that and every file I open on it is read only.

I have dual boot, so on Windows everything works as expected, the problem is only on Ubuntu. Anyone knows what could be the issue?

All of hard disk expect for the one on which Ubuntu is installed. I get these messages:

```
mount: /dev/sdb1: can't find in /etc/fstab
mount: /dev/sdc5: can't find in /etc/fstab
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the output of `mount`? And explain which mount point is read only?

Comment: I guess this is a given, but what is the output of `ls -la /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/fstab`? Please add that to the question as it will be helpful for people trying to help you

Comment: What format are these partitions? If NTFS it may be a Windows update turned fast start up back on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: Yep : disable the fast-startup feature of windows or simply perform a real full shutdown of windows with this (windows) command : `shutdown /f /p`

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thank you!!!